# How to handle page change errors in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm writing a jQuery Mobile application that requires user authentication. The same user cannot have her session open from multiple locations: if user logins from another browser, the previous session is marked as dead.

If the user attempts to move to another page with the browser with the dead session, "Error loading page" message is displayed. This is bad because user might not know why she's getting this error. Is it possible to tap in to the error event so I could check for the status of the session and redirect user to the login page if the session is dead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up forking jQuery Mobile and adding an ability to add custom error handler: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/pull/2504 I think this superior to the other suggestions because it doesn't add any overhead except when the error actually occurs.

UPDATE: There will be a new pageloadfailed event in jQuery Mobile RC1. That will solve this problem elegantly and according to project standards.

Answer (score 3):

How about the

```
pagechangefailed
```

event?

It is fired when the pageload fails, which seems to be the case.

More info on http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html

Comment: Yes, this is available in the recent versions. However I had this problem back in September when this wasn't implemented yet. In my own answer I've described the pageloadfailed event. Apparently pagechangefailed might suffice as well.

Answer (score 2):

Related:

- [Ajax - I need to check whether a valid session exists before every AJAX requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303795/ajax-i-need-to-check-whether-a-valid-session-exists-before-every-ajax-requests)
- [How to manage a redirect request after a jQuery Ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199099/how-to-manage-a-redirect-request-after-a-jquery-ajax-call)

You could use something like

> **pagebeforeshow**
>
> Triggered on the page being shown, before its transition begins.

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b3/docs/api/events.html

Example (pseudo code):

```
$('#pageId').live('pagebeforeshow',function(event, ui){
    // check session here
    if(!$session) {
        // redirect to login
        $.mobile.changePage('#login');
    }
});
```

Comment: This is a bit better solution. However this still feels a bit overkill. I was thinking about doing a fork of jQuery Mobile and adding a subscribable error event so I could handle the error only when it happens. Then again premature optimization is hazardous so maybe I'll roll with your suggestion for now. :)

Comment: This didn't help after all. pagebeforeshow and pagebeforehide events aren't triggered if the page loading fails.

Comment: My next suggestion would be to use AJAX and check the Apache response, Example: if you get a 200 response you're good, else ... might need to map more responses as well as this is just a concept

Comment: Or have the AJAX request the page and have the back end (like PHP) validate the Session, if not valid use PHP to send the URL desired as the response. Example: AJAX request secure.php page, PHP checks session, if session is good return secure.php else return login.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$(a).click(function(){
    // check for session?
});
```

Comment: That's one way to solve it but it might be a bit excessive. That would (about) double the amount of requests and as the application is used mainly on mobile devices, that might become a noticeable problem.